# Filter only digit sequences containing a given set of digits

Tags: performance, algorithm, data-structures, filtering, lookup

I have a large list of digit strings like this one. The individual strings are relatively short (say less than 50 digits).

```
data = [
  '300303334',
  '53210234',
  '123456789',
  '5374576807063874'
]
```

I need to find out a efficient data structure (speed first, memory second) and algorithm which returns only those strings that are composed of a given set of digits.

Example results:

```
filter(data, [0,3,4]) = ['300303334']
filter(data, [0,1,2,3,4,5]) = ['300303334', '53210234']
```

The data list will usually fit into memory.

Comment: Does the data change often?

Comment: No, it will change very rarely.

Comment: Then use a hash table, go through all digits in each number and place it under each hash 0-9. the number 123 should be placed under 1, 2 and 3 etc. It will take some time to create it, but the retrieval will be fast. If you want to retrieve the numbers that have 1,6,7, just union the lists in 1, 6 and 7.

Comment: Yes, I guess I can do that with a slight modification - I'll only store references to the data items as values in the hash table. I was also thinking if a Bloom filter would be useful here - I've never used it before.

Comment: The problem with @BjørnBråthen's answer is that if you ask for strings containing 1, 2, and 3, it will include "1234", "197832", etc., rather than strings that contain only the requested digits. You would have to combine this approach with a final filter that checks each string in the final result to see if it contains *only* the requested digits.

Comment: I don't see how a Bloom filter can help you here.

Comment: How large is your "large list of digit strings?"

Comment: The number of items in the list will grow steadily over time. While I'm starting with only 100 of items, I'm planning for the phase when I get to the order of 10^5 or 10^6. The length of an item is pretty much short and well bounded, like I wrote before. But I made an oversimplification of the problem by listing only 10 digits as possible symbols. Now that I look at the answers that was quite stupid of me, because it will be in thousands and the efficiency seems to depend on that very much. Should I edit the question or start a new one?

Answer (score 1):

For each digit, precompute a postings list that *don't* contain the digit.

```
postings = [[] for _ in xrange(10)]
for i, d in enumerate(data):
    for j in xrange(10):
        digit = str(j)
        if digit not in d:
            postings[j].append(i)
```

Now, to find all strings that contain, for example, just the digits [1, 3, 5] you can merge the postings lists for the other digits (ie: 0, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9).

```
def intersect_postings(p0, p1):
    i0, i1 = next(p0), next(p1)
    while True:
         if i0 == i1:
            yield i0
            i0, i1 = next(p0), next(p1)
         elif i0 < i1: i0 = next(p0)
         else: i1 = next(p1)

def find_all(digits):
    p = None
    for d in xrange(10):
        if d not in digits:
            if p is None: p = iter(postings[d])
            else: p = intersect_postings(p, iter(postings[d]))
    return (data[i] for i in p) if p else iter(data)

print list(find_all([0, 3, 4]))
print list(find_all([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
```

Answer (score 1):

A string can be encoded by a 10-bit number. There are 2^10, or 1,024 possible values.

So create a dictionary that uses an integer for a key and a list of strings for the value.

Calculate the value for each string and add that string to the list of strings for that value.

General idea:

```
Dictionary Lookup;

for each (string in list)
    value = 0;
    for each character in string
        set bit N in value, where N is the character (0-9)
    Lookup[value] += string  // adds string to list for this value in dictionary
```

Then, to get a list of the strings that match your criteria, just compute the value and do a direct dictionary lookup.

So if the user asks for strings that contain only 3, 5, and 7:

```
value = (1 << 3) || (1 << 5) || (1 << 7);
list = Lookup[value];
```

Note that, as Matt pointed out in comment below, this will only return strings that contain all three digits. So, for example, it wouldn't return 37. That seems like a fatal flaw to me.

### Edit

If the number of symbols you have to deal with is very large, then the number of possible combinations becomes too large for this solution to be practical.

With a large number of symbols, I'd recommend an inverted index as suggested in the comments, combined with a secondary filter that removes the strings that contain extraneous digits.

Comment: Great answer! With respect, I think if the user asks for strings containing only the digit 2, bit 2 would be set in your value, which means you should give him back the list at Lookup[(1<<2)]. So, if he asks for digits 3,5 & 7 you should return Lookup[(1<<3)|(1<<5)|(1<<7)], shouldn't you?

Comment: Or, put it another way, if he asks for strings containing zero, bit zero would be set, which requires zero shifts.

Comment: @MarkSetchell: Thanks for the correction. Don't know what I was thinking there.

Comment: Doesn't this fail to handle his second example: filter(data, [0,1,2,3,4,5]) = ['300303334', '53210234'] - you would only return numbers that contain exactly the digits requested, not a subset.

Comment: @mattnewport Look at mine [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20291320/49197). When you insert string into all lookup members which conforms to `(m & i) == m` where `m` is mask of current string and `i` is lookup index it solves the problem. See `insert2lu`.

Comment: Your modified solution works but for certain inputs it could end up using quite a lot of memory since you store pointers to the same strings many times under many different keys. I think it may well be a good solution for the OP but I wonder if there is a more memory efficient option.

Comment: @mattnewport: Agreed. Worst case is 10x the memory (every string contains every digit). There are more memory efficient solutions, but they're slower. The speed/memory tradeoff is unfortunately something we have to live with. I suppose it's possible to build a tree of some type ... hmmmm . . .

Comment: I think it can actually be worse than that, strings only containing 1 and 2 for example will have their pointers stored under all the keys which have 1 and 2 as a subset so if all your strings consist of only 1s and 2s they will all be stored 256 times.

Comment: @mattnewport: He said "digit strings," so we're only worried about 10 characters, not 256. Worst case is that every string contains every character. Even if the strings contained any Unicode character, he said max length was 50, so worst case would be 50x. Finally, he said "speed first, memory second." So we go with the fastest possible unless there's a memory problem.

Comment: Also, comments in another post indicate that he's really working with thousands of different digits. So what we have, in effect, is thousands of "words" making up "sentences" of 50 or fewer words each. That sounds like an excellent application for a standard inverted index.

Comment: Yes, @JimMischel, that's the use case I have. I'm sorry to have oversimplified :(. Inverted index does sound like the obvious hammer for this nail. By having a bounded length of an item, I will perform at most 50 inverted index lookups per query (actually only uniq(item) number of lookups) followed by a union operation on the lookup results.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a function f which constructs a bitmask for each string with bit i set if digit i is in the string.

For example,

```
f('0')    = 0b0000000001
f('00')   = 0b0000000001
f('1')    = 0b0000000010
f('1100') = 0b0000000011
```

Then I suggest storing a list of strings for each bitmask.

For example,

```
Bitmask 0b0000000001 -> ['0','00']
```

Once you have prepared this data structure (which is the same size as your original list), you can then easily access all the strings for a particular filter by accessing all lists where the bitmask is a subset of the digits in your filter.

So for your example of filter [0,3,4] you would return the lists from:

```
Strings containing just 0
Strings containing just 3
Strings containing just 4
Strings containing 0 and 3
Strings containing 0 and 4
Strings containing 3 and 4
Strings containing 0 and 3 and 4
```

### Example Python Code

```
from collections import defaultdict
import itertools

raw_data = [
  '300303334',
  '53210234',
  '123456789',
  '5374576807063874'
]

def preprocess(raw_data):
    data = defaultdict(list)
    for s in raw_data:
        bitmask = 0
        for digit in s:
            bitmask |= 1<<int(digit)
        data[bitmask].append(s)
    return data

def filter(data,mask):
    for r in range(len(mask)):
        for m in itertools.combinations(mask,r+1):
            bitmask = sum(1<<digit for digit in m)
            for s in data[bitmask]:
                yield s

data = preprocess(raw_data)

for a in filter(data, [0,1,2,3,4,5]):
    print a
```

Comment: Sounds good at first, but actually constructing the permutations of "Strings containing x and y and ..." sets would prove to be a challenge on its own even for just 10 digts. Bit I oversimplified with just digits - I'll have a couple thousand other symbols instead of digits.

Comment: If you have lots of symbols then I agree this approach is not very good and you are probably better off just computing the intersection of sets for each symbol.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do some performance tests in the following days. At this stage, I'm just looking for brainstorms of good approaches, so your input helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Just for kicks, I have coded up [Jim's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/56778/jim-mischel) lovely algorithm and the Perl is here if anyone wants to play with it. Please do not accept this as an answer or anything, pass all credit to Jim:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $Debug=1;
my $Nwords=1000;

my ($word,$N,$value,$i,$j,$k);
my (@dictionary,%Lookup);

################################################################################
# Generate "words" with random number of characters 5-30
################################################################################
print "DEBUG: Generating $Nwords word dictionary\n" if $Debug;
for($i=0;$i<$Nwords;$i++){
   $j = rand(25) + 5;   # length of this word
   $word="";
   for($k=0;$k<$j;$k++){
      $word = $word . int(rand(10));
   }
   $dictionary[$i]=$word;
   print "$word\n" if $Debug;
}

# Add some obvious test cases
$dictionary[++$i]="0" x 50;
$dictionary[++$i]="1" x 50;
$dictionary[++$i]="2" x 50;
$dictionary[++$i]="3" x 50;
$dictionary[++$i]="4" x 50;
$dictionary[++$i]="5" x 50;
$dictionary[++$i]="6" x 50;
$dictionary[++$i]="7" x 50;
$dictionary[++$i]="8" x 50;
$dictionary[++$i]="9" x 50;
$dictionary[++$i]="0123456789";

################################################################################
# Encode words
################################################################################
for $word (@dictionary){
   $value=0;
   for($i=0;$i<length($word);$i++){
      $N=substr($word,$i,1);
      $value |= 1 << $N;
   }
   push(@{$Lookup{$value}},$word);
   print "DEBUG: $word encoded as $value\n" if $Debug;
}

################################################################################
# Do lookups
################################################################################
   while(1){
      print "Enter permitted digits, separated with commas: ";
      my $line=<STDIN>;
      my @digits=split(",",$line);
      $value=0;
      for my $d (@digits){
        $value |= 1<<$d;
      }
      print "Value: $value\n";
      print join(", ",@{$Lookup{$value}}),"\n\n" if defined $Lookup{$value};
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I like [Jim Mischel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/56778/jim-mischel)'s approach. It has pretty efficient look up and bounded memory usage. Code in C follows:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>

enum {
    zero = '0',
    nine = '9',
    numbers = nine - zero + 1,
    masks = 1 << numbers,
};

typedef uint16_t mask;

struct list {
    char *s;
    struct list *next;
};

typedef struct list list_cell;
typedef struct list *list;

static inline int is_digit(char c) { return c >= zero && c <= nine; }
static inline mask char2mask(char c) { return 1 << (c - zero); }

static inline mask add_char2mask(mask m, char c) {
    return m | (is_digit(c) ? char2mask(c) : 0);
}

static inline int is_set(mask m, mask n) { return (m & n) != 0; }

static inline int is_set_char(mask m, char c) { return is_set(m, char2mask(c)); }

static inline int is_submask(mask sub, mask m) { return (sub & m) == sub; }

static inline char *sprint_mask(char buf[11], mask m) {
    char *s = buf;
    char i;
    for(i = zero; i <= nine; i++)
        if(is_set_char(m, i)) *s++ = i;
    *s = 0;
    return buf;
}

static inline mask get_mask(char *s) {
    mask m=0;
    for(; *s; s++)
        m = add_char2mask(m, *s);
    return m;
}

static inline int is_empty(list l) { return !l; }

static inline list insert(list *l, char *s) {
    list cell = (list)malloc(sizeof(list_cell));
    cell->s = s;
    cell->next = *l;
    return *l = cell;
}

static void *foreach(void *f(char *, void *), list l, void *init) {
    for(; !is_empty(l); l = l->next)
        init = f(l->s, init);
    return init;
}

struct printer_state {
    int first;
    FILE *f;
};

static void *prin_list_member(char *s, void *data) {
    struct printer_state *st = (struct printer_state *)data;
    if(st->first) {
        fputs(", ", st->f);
    } else
        st->first = 1;
    fputs(s, st->f);
    return data;
}

static void print_list(list l) {
    struct printer_state st = {.first = 0, .f = stdout};
    foreach(prin_list_member, l, (void *)&st);
    putchar('\n');
}

static list *init_lu(void) { return (list *)calloc(sizeof(list), masks); }

static list *insert2lu(list lu[masks], char *s) {
    mask i, m = get_mask(s);
    if(m)       // skip string without any number
        for(i = m; i < masks; i++)
            if(is_submask(m, i))
                insert(lu+i, s);
    return lu;
}

int usage(const char *name) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s filename\n", name);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

#define handle_error(msg) \
    do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } while (0)

static inline void chomp(char *s) { if( (s = strchr(s, '\n')) ) *s = '\0'; }

list *load_file(FILE *f) {
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    list *lu = init_lu();

    for(; (read = getline(&line, &len, f)) != -1; line = NULL) {
        chomp(line);
        insert2lu(lu, line);
    }

    return lu;
}

void read_reqs(list *lu) {
    char *line;
    char buf[11];

    for(; (line = readline("> ")); free(line))
        if(*line) {
            add_history(line);
            mask m = get_mask(line);
            printf("mask: %s\nstrings: ", sprint_mask(buf, m));
            print_list(lu[m]);
        };

    putchar('\n');
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[] ) {
    const char *name = argv[0];
    FILE *f;
    list *lu;

    if(argc != 2) return usage(name);

    f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if(!f) handle_error("open");
    lu = load_file(f);
    fclose(f);

    read_reqs(lu);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

To compile use

```
gcc -lreadline -o digitfilter digitfilter.c
```

And test run:

```
$ cat data.txt 
300303334
53210234
123456789
5374576807063874
$ ./digitfilter data.txt 
> 034
mask: 034
strings: 300303334
> 0,1,2,3,4,5
mask: 012345
strings: 53210234, 300303334
> 0345678
mask: 0345678
strings: 5374576807063874, 300303334
```

Answer (score 0):

Put each value into a set-- Eg.: '300303334'={3, 0, 4}.

Since the length of your data items are bound by a constant (50), 
you can do these at **O(1)** time for each item using Java **HashSet**. The overall complexity of this phase adds up to **O(n)**.

For each filter set, use **containsAll()** of **HashSet** to see whether 
each of these data items is a subset of your filter. Takes **O(n)**.

Takes **O(m*n)** in the overall where **n** is the number of data items and **m** the number of filters.

Comment: I was thinking about a hash as well. One thing to consider, though, is that there may be a significant number of queries where looking up all combinations of the query symbols may be much faster than O(n*m). For example, consider 10,000,000 items and 100 queries of 10 symbols each. That would mean 100*(2^10-1) = 102300 look-ups vs 10,000,000*100.